# Thumbnail image gallery with Javascript without plugin

Tags: javascript

I was looking for a tutorial do create a image gallery with thumbnail and slider option, but find many examples Jquery and plugins and just slider or just thumbnail gallery . I found example with mouseover, but I need to be on click, how it Works top remove the old image and insert the new image?
I am trying do build a code with best pratices and I want to load the images only when select a thumbnail.

This is the only example I find, but I don't want do select all the images from the page, only the thumbnails. How can I mix thumbnail gallery with slider in the code?

Thumbnail

http://www.web-development-institute.com/how-create-simple-image-gallery-javascript

Slider
http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

Comment: Create the thumbnails and full images on the Server the exact size that they will be in HTML, to avoid the process of Vector Scaling. Store your image file names in an array that you increment depending on which way you click, using a click Event. If you want to loop over at the end of loop just increment back to 0. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where's ***your*** code?

Comment: I understand not wanting a plugin that includes the kitchen sink, but what other arguments are there for re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Winterfruit, i don't know what is the intention but i think it's to see how i create the code with vanilla javascript.  I didn't  pass the test. But i create a vailla version and a jquery version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with Bootstrap's carousel ? [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

This feature the indicators where you can work around to put your thumbnail in. Of course you will have to do some css override to make its look as desired.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
      <!-- put your thumbnail here-->
    </li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
```

...

Comment: Yes, but to apply for the job I need to do with vanilla Javascript without any plugins including bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after a lot of research, i am aswering if someone need:

Jquery version

```
<https://codepen.io/Gisesonia/pen/vpPvaW>
```

Vanilla javascript 
    https://codepen.io/Gisesonia/pen/GyLGeL